# java fonts not displaying properly

Tags: java, fonts

when i import a font from a file, it displays really weirdly. it was supposed to say "TEST", but it just said "_".

here is my code:

```
public void paint(Graphics g2){
Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)g2;
//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="FontGetter">

Font f = null;
try {
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    ge.registerFont((f = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, getClass().getResourceAsStream("Triforce.ttf"))));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch(FontFormatException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//</editor-fold>
g.setFont(f.deriveFont(2));
g.drawString("sdfsdfetf", 100, 100);
}
```

Comment: 1- Where is the font actually stored in relation to the code; 2- Don't load resources within the `paint` method

Answer (score 1):

As specified by the [`Font#createFont`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#createFont(int,%20java.io.InputStream)) Java Docs

> ... The new Font is created with a **point size of 1** and style PLAIN ...

(emphasis applied by me)

This means that you need to derive a new `Font` instance from this `Font` with the required properties, for example

```
try {
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    Font f = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Triforce.ttf"));
    if (!ge.registerFont(f)) {
        System.out.println("Unable to register font");
    }
    f = f.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 24);
    setFont(f);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (FontFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[image: Font]

You should pre-load you font (and apply it's properties) outside of the context of the paint method.  Painting should run as fast as possible and will be called multiple times, sometimes in quick succession.  Loading resources within any paint method wastes time and resource...

As an example...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test1();
    }

    public Test1() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
                Font f = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Triforce.ttf"));
                if (!ge.registerFont(f)) {
                    System.out.println("Unable to register font");
                }
                f = f.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 24);
                setFont(f);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FontFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            String text = "Hello world";
            int x = (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
            int y = ((getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) + fm.getAscent()) / 2;
            g2d.drawString(text, x, y);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```