# Swing - How to add customized font to JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtextarea

My tool basically read the PDF and print the pdf's content in `JTextArea`. Everything working fine until my PDF contains **PH Mirjan** fonts for Arabic. My text area shows some junk character as per below.

[image]

How do I solve this?

My default font for the text area is **Arial Unicode MS**. Is there anyway I can configure the text area's font to take? Let say I downloaded **PH Mirjan** in my local, how to change the text area font to the downloaded one. Any advice or references links is highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

```
try (InputStream is = NewJFrame.class.getResourceAsStream("/GE SS Two Bold.otf")) 
        {
            Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
            font = font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 24f);
            jTextArea1.setFont(font);
            jTextArea1.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
```

and its give me this Exception.

**Exception**

> java.awt.FontFormatException: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
>       at sun.font.TrueTypeFont.init(TrueTypeFont.java:558)
>       at sun.font.TrueTypeFont.(TrueTypeFont.java:191)
>       at sun.font.CFontManager.createFont2D(CFontManager.java:161)
>       at java.awt.Font.(Font.java:614)
>       at java.awt.Font.createFont0(Font.java:968)
>       at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:876)

Any idea why i'm getting this.?

Comment: `JTextArea#setFont`, but you need to use something like [`Font.createFont`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#createFont(int,%20java.io.File)) to load it first (assuming it's not loaded in the system fonts of the OS), otherwise you should be able to create it by name. For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177348/font-awesome-with-swing/24177458#24177458) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809337/java-fonts-not-displaying-properly/27809588#27809588)

Comment: or [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278648/how-to-change-font-in-java-gui-application/24278825#24278825)

Comment: Hopefully, this [another example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9651404/1057230), will also help you in your good endeavour :-)

Comment: ..or [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13718134/418556) or [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6965149/418556) ..  I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate of *some* exact question..

Answer (score 1):

Why is the font name is `.tt` instead of `.ttf` ? 
The case might be it is not a `ttf` file or corrupted that the exception happens

```
    try {
        Font NARROW = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fonts/DSS.ttf"));   
        NARROW = NARROW.deriveFont(17f);       
    } catch (FontFormatException | IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Exception loading fonts "+ex);
    }
```

I know it is pretty  much the same code , try this on other `ttf` files. `Exception` should not be there.